# Group by, more than once in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to find all the records that I occur more than once in a row.

**Sample Data:**

```
NAME 
---- 
 B    
 B    
 B    
 C    
 C    
 A
 C
 A
 A
```

**Result:**

```
NAME COUNT
---- ---- 
 B    3   
 C    2 
 A    2
```

Comment: You'll need another column to order on. Look into gaps and islands.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment under the question, you need an additional column to do this; if you don't this is impossible. With an additional always ascending column though you can do something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #T (ID int, [Name] char(1));
INSERT INTO #T
VALUES(1,'B'),    
      (2,'B'),    
      (3,'B'),    
      (4,'C'),    
      (5,'C'),    
      (6,'A'),
      (7,'C'),
      (8,'A'),
      (9,'A');
GO

WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT [Name],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY ID) AS Grp
    FROM #T)
SELECT [Name],
       COUNT([Name]) AS [Count]
FROM Grps
GROUP BY [Name],
         Grp
HAVING COUNT([Name]) >= 2
ORDER BY [Count] DESC,
         Grp DESC;


GO
DROP TABLE #T;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to get the desired result (It has some similarity with @Larnu solution):

First I add a new row ('trash') at the end, because I will need it when I use the window function lead. Then I generate row numbers and set the start of each group (with zero). Next I get only the rows start of each group, and rest the row number of the next row with the actual row number  (this is the count of each group). Finally I group by name and get max name_count (dismissing groups of one name).

```
WITH 
   union_trash AS (SELECT * FROM t UNION ALL SELECT 'trash'),
   group_head AS (SELECT 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn,
                     name,
                     (CASE WHEN name = lag(name, 1) OVER () THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS group_start
                  FROM union_trash),
   group_count AS (SELECT name, lead(rn) OVER () - rn AS name_count
                   FROM group_head
                   WHERE group_start = 0)


SELECT name, max(name_count) AS max_name_count
FROM group_count
WHERE name_count IS NOT NULL AND name_count > 1
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY max(name_count) DESC, name;
```

You have to take in account that the order of the rows result of a query could change if you don't order them using some criteria.

This query return the names that appear at least in two consecutive rows (but it not return the count (or max count) consecutive names appear):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM (
SELECT name, 
   name = lead(name, 1, 1) OVER () OR name = lag(name, 1, 1) OVER () AS p
FROM t) AS aux
WHERE p != 0
```

This query not produce the desired result (group by name and count(*) the amount of rows with the same name):

```
SELECT name, count(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

Comment: Take a look at shawnt00's comment above.

Comment: This'll incorrect return 3 for both `'a'` and `'c'`.

Comment: Ok, I haven't undertood your question.

Comment: Do you know that the order of the rows result of a query can change if you don't order them using some criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `COUNT` clause after `SELECT` and add a `GROUP BY` at the end.

`SELECT name, COUNT(name) FROM <your_table> GROUP BY name`

Comment: Take a look at shawnt00's comment above.

Comment: This'll incorrect return 3 for both `'a'` and `'c'`.